# Why was my question closed and incorrectly called "homework?"

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

Why was [What happens if other contractors also agree to accept a lower sum in full satisfaction of their own debts?](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/61388) closed? I admit it's long, but I don't want to risk losing context by shortening it.

My comment to [Trish's comment](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/61388/what-happens-if-other-contractors-also-agree-to-accept-a-lower-sum-in-full-satis#comment128497_61388) appears removed. by a mod. But it's rude and wrong. This isn't homework. I quoted that question from [this book of model questions and answers](https://global.oup.com/ukhe/product/concentrate-questions-and-answers-contract-law-9780198817673?). Apology if I was supposed to write this, but I didn't know people like Trish would just wrongly presume that  a question is homework.

Let me know if this is a separate question, but why so many downvotes?

Answer (score 6):

The stated close reason is that the question "needs details or clarity."  Since I was one of five users voting that – but *not* one of the six users downvoting the question (appropriately, in my view) – I will emphasize the *clarity* part: It appears impossible to decipher the question at the end of ~600 background words – from an unnamed source – without poring over all of those words.

Trish's comment is curt but appropriate: **While your question may not literally be homework, what you have posted is a bad question (for this site) *for the same reasons* as literal homework questions:** you are asking every reader to do a bunch of work that you as the asker should do.

You give readers no reason to believe your question is interesting, coherent, or otherwise worth their time.  I still haven't read the cited text.  Maybe if you distilled it into an intriguing question I would be enticed to.

---

Note that five of the six questions you have posted on the main site have negative votes.  This is the community's way of telling you that you are not making positive contributions.  As of this moment you haven't even [taken the tour](https://law.stackexchange.com/tour).  Please do that.  Look at the [help pages](https://law.stackexchange.com/help), and perhaps spend some time perusing questions, answers, and comments that have positive votes to get a feel for what works here.

Answer (score 2):

### The question is verbose and obscures the point

This is an example of the same question more concisely:

The rule in *Pinnel's Case* 5 Co Rep 117a and confirmed by the House of Lords in *Foakes v Beer* (1884) 9 App Cas 605 limits the ability to extinguish existing debts unless full payment has been made. I have read that there is an exception to this rule if the arrangement is a ‘composition agreement by creditors’. What does that mean?

Comment: Thanks! You're much better at concision than I am, which is why you have 109k rep! In the future, can you just edit my question pls?

Answer (score 0):

I had asked to have your comment remove, because I felt your comment was rude while mine was a very short matter of fact statement, that questions that appear to be homework are very disliked on this stack and banned on several others. In fact, Physics and Math SE have explicitly banned asking questions that appear to be homework. You depict a question and an answer and want us to argue why the answer is correct? That' what law schools generally give as homework.

Questions that quote extensive text often are "homework" or rather "Homework style". They show little to no own research and want to have everything explained in them - which is a huge mess. Especially if you don't tell here you got the text from.

Comment: I'm sorry if you found my reply rude, but I found your comment arrogant and presumptuous. "mine was a very short matter of fact statement" No it wasn't. It wasn't a statement of fact. You didn't even ask if my question was about homework, you just presumed. But it would've been more reasonable to presume that it wasn't homework, because I pasted the answer! If it was homework, how can I have pasted the answer?

Comment: "In fact, Physics and Math SE have explicitly banned asking questions that appear to be homework." Again you're wrong. They contain many exercises and problems from textbooks.

Comment: On math, the hurdle for [Homework is huge](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question), making them effectively banned. Physics just [Closes Homework-like questions.](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7407/generalizing-the-homework-policy) unless you show your own work.

Comment: When your first two questions on the site are asking why your answer to a multiple choice quiz was wrong, and then you repeatedly post enormous chunks from a textbook asking for someone to explain a point that is similar if not identical to an essay starter, yeah, you're asking a homework question. Your homework? Maybe not. But acting otherwise when people point this out, and getting rude in response? Your questions seek someone else to explain a point that is clearly meant for your development, and request that someone else just edit your posts for you instead of making that effort yourself.

Comment: @Nij "getting rude in response". How was I rude? please see https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1205/why-was-my-question-closed-and-incorrectly-called-homework/1211#comment3041_1207.

Comment: @17y.o. I am well aware of my own question. Your answer there is not an answer to the question posted there, by the way.

Comment: @Trish My answer there rebuts some assumptions in your question there, and rebuts your comment above ^^^.

Comment: First of all, let me explain how flagging works on the stack: A comment or question is put in a queue for a moderator to review with a reason. So it needs to qualify as violating site guidelines in two sets of eyes. You instantly alleged something about me or that I alleged your question is homework in your answering comment. That is rude. **Never do that**. I had just a short comment that the community as a whole (we) does not answer someone's homework (no matter if it is or not!). It is a very short and objective statement of fact. I never stated *that* or *if* your question is homework.